# how to use arrayadapter.getview method

Tags: android, listview, android-view

Here I defined a **SiteAdapter** and extends from **ArrayAdapter**:

```
public class SiteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Site> {
private int resourceId;
private List<Site> sites = null;
private Context context;
public SiteAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Site> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    this.context = context;
    this.resourceId = resource;
    this.sites = objects;
}

@Override
public Site getItem(int position) {
    return sites.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return sites.size();
}

//get the viewpage which inflate by site_layout.xml file
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Site site = getItem(position);
    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = vi.inflate(resourceId, null);
    }
    //this place we need to get the whole widget in site_layout.xml file
    ImageView i1 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
    TextView address = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.address);
    TextView t1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
    TextView t3 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.distance);
    i1.setImageResource(site.getImageId());
    address.setText(site.getAddress());
    String name = site.getName();
    String result = parse(name);
    //set name of the view
    t1.setText(name);
    t3.setText("<" + site.getDistance() + "m");

    return view;
}
```

and in the MainActivity, I set the **ListView** using this site adapter, and  I allocated an R.drawable.blank value to the only **ImageView** and now I need to change the **ImageView**, then get each row view through siteadapter getview method, the view returned but the question is why **ImageView** inside such view can't replace a new value(image), the result always turn out the previous R.drawable.blank ImageView:

here is MainActivity snippet:

```
View view = siteAdapter.getView(2, null, listView);
        ImageView image1 = ((ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail));
        image1.invalidate();
        image1.setImageResource(R.drawable.amap_end);
        siteAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: First consider using ViewHolder pattern. Check what's the value inside `getImageId()`

Comment: just change the **setImage** value for your particular arraylist item, which you want to change and call **adapter.notifyDataSetChange()**. It will change your image in list view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is you do not have to call `getView()` from your activity . It is only called by Adapter .

Now if you want to change your `imageView` , you should change it from your sites list that is links to your adapter from activity , then call `notifyDataSetChanged()` from adapter .

**Activity** :

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        // setUpViews
        SiteAdapter adapter = new SiteAdapter(context,List<Site> sites);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        // changing imageView
        Site site = sites.get(position);
        site.setImage(R.drawable.*);

        // updating site into list with new image
        sites.set(position,site);

        // refresh the listView
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

**However ,** consider to use `RecycleView` instead of `ListView` .

Comment: i know that way and your means, but site object image attribute is an integer type but here i need to download image from server and store in the cache file, so setImage(R.drawable.*) can no longer use for File or bitmap.

Comment: Well , in this situation you have to provide the image urls from somewhere , then you can use Glide or Picasso libraries to download bitmap asynchronously . Finally after downloading those libs are going to show your bitmaps in right position of your listView .

http://www.androidhive.info/2016/04/android-glide-image-library-building-image-gallery-app/

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-working-with-picasso--cms-22149

Comment: actually i really wonder why getView can not use, that made me weird,I even don't know why.

Comment: Its the same as OnCreate method in Activity . Do you call this method by your own ? . Actually your application does.

Comment: after a long time practice i find out your answer, get view method can not be called by user but only application itself.get two vote down!!!oh my god.....